# How to find out if xml contains two or more equal attribute names with xsl and Xpath?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm a beginner with xsl and path. I would like to find a way how to accomplish the following with xsl and path:

1. check if there's ID attributes which have same value (e.g. 001 and 001)
2. if there is, print text to html page
3. if there isn't (in other words, if all attribute names are unique), print another text to html page.

my xml is following:

```
 <shop>

  <product>
    <cookie ID="001">
       <price>2</price>
    </cookie>
  </product>

  <product>
    <bread ID="002">
       <price>5</price>
    </bread>
  </product>

  <product>
    <milk ID="003">
       <price>2</price>
    </milk>
  </product>

</shop>
```

My idea was to use something like this:

```
<xsl:if test="count(distinct-values(@ID*) < count(//product)">
    <p>ID values are not unique!</p>
</xsl:if>
```

If there's less distinct ID values than there is products, write a text "ID values are not unique"

This obviously doesn't work. Could some please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check a condition based on total items, and total distinct items like so: `count(distinct-values(//@ID)) = count(//@ID)` And as Richard pointed out, `distinct-values` is XPath 2.0 only, are you working with 1.0 or 2.0?

Also just to be clear, using `//` will start at the root and look at all nodes for that condition, so if you just want to check `@ID` nodes within `<shop>`, use `//shop/@ID`

If you're using 1.0, you'll likely know due to an error explicitly telling you the function `distinct-values` can't be found, but you could use this in 1.0 just in case:

**XPath 1.0 solution:**

```
boolean(//shop/product[./node()/@ID = preceding-sibling::product/node()/@ID or ./node()/@ID = following-sibling::product/node()/@ID])
```

In the first one I didn't realize the node name changing, that was my fault. Just substitute this condition in place of your current one, like so:

```
<xsl:if test="boolean(//shop/product[./node()/@ID = preceding-sibling::product/node()/@ID or ./node()/@ID = following-sibling::product/node()/@ID] )">
    <p>ID values are not unique!</p>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your replies! I'm using XPath 1.0 so that leaves the the distinct-values function out. The XML file I posted would be actually be longer with more products. How could I solve my problem with XPath 1.0. I'm not sure if I understood your last example.

Comment: Oops, you probably didn't understand it because it was wrong, for some reason I read your xml incorrectly. I updated my answer!

Comment: I tried your solution and it worked like a charm! Thank you so much, this was really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

try `distinct-values(//@ID)`

Also, I think distict-values is only available in XPath 2.0.

Comment: Good point. I'm using XPath 1.0 so distinct-values() is out of the question. How could my problem be solved using XPath 1.0? Thank you!